# How to take advantage of multiples series with the same behaviour for forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, modeling

I'm quite new to statistics and forecasting, and I have to build a model to forecast monthly sales of different related products in a bunch of cities.

Seasonal ARIMA seams to be a good model for that, but that implies creating a model for each of the products in each cities (I have about 300 series). I don't think there is anything wrong with that, but I wonder if there is a model that can take all the series into account at the same time to improve the forecast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use generalized regression model for producing hierarchical forecasts from the individual forecasts.

Here is a link:

https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/4

Comment: +1. This approach has been found to improve forecast accuracy *across the hierarchy*, see [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947311000971) and [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207008000691).

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for, but it is still pretty neat and it will certainly be useful. Do you know an implementation in Python?

Comment: @Pafnouti No, I do not know but perhaps you can write these equations down by using linear algebra libraries in Python?

Comment: @StephanKolassa It seems that Prof Hyndman is working quite heavily in this field also... :)

Comment: He is. He co-authored both the open source textbook you linked to *and* the hierarchical time series approach, *and* he created the [`hts` package for R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hts/) for hierarchical time series - no python implementation, though - *and* he's editor-in-chief of the [IJF](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/01692070) *and* he [posts here frequently](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/159/rob-hyndman). Take him seriously.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on the inside-R website which uses signal decomposition for training and testing and then forecasting with a neural net and which might be a useful alternative to generalized regression models. R code is supplied.

[link here](http://www.inside-r.org/howto/time-series-analysis-and-order-prediction-r)

Answer (score -1):

Try finding the common factors, and model these factors. For instance, you could run [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), and see if there's a few factors that explain the variance of your 300 series. It is possible that you may find a handful of principal components explain a huge chunk of the variance of all 300 series. In this case you'll model these few factors only. Then you can recover the original series from factors.